# Compute difference of dense matrix at non-zero elements of another sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a `n x n` matrix `W` a `n`-diemensional vector `U` and a scalar `p > 1`. I want to compute `W * (np.abs(U[:,np.newaxis] - U) ** p)`, where `*`, `**` and `abs` are understood element wise (as in numpy).

Now the problem is that `U[:,np.newaxis] - U` does not fit into memory. However, `W` is a sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse`), so I don't actually have to compute all entries of `U[:,np.newaxis] - U`, but only those, where `W` is not zero.

How can I compute `W * (np.abs(U[:,np.newaxis] - U) ** p)` most efficiently in terms of computation time and memory, ideally doing only sparse operations, without a step through `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, we can just do the desired computation using `W.nonzero()`

Assuming `W` is a `csc_matrix`:

```
nonzero = W.nonzero()
values = np.abs(U[nonzero[0]] - U[nonzero[1]]) ** p
A = sparse.csc_matrix((values, nonzero), shape=(U.size, U.size))
W.multiply(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make use of the sparseness you could apply the distributive law so

```
 C = W * (np.abs(U[:,np.newaxis] - U) ** p)
```

would result in

```
rtW = W**(1/p)
C = (rtW * np.abs(U[:,np.newaxis] - rtW * U) ** p
```

note that this only makes sense as long the entries of `W` aren't negative. But we can remedy that by using

```
rtW = np.abs(W)**(1/p)
signW = np.sign(W)
C = signW * (rtW * np.abs(U[:,np.newaxis] - rtW * U) ** p
```